# Does Firebase supports certificate pinning?

Tags: node.js, firebase

Having a hard time finding if Firebase supports certificate pinning?
This question refers to both 2.4 & 3 Firebase node.js SDK versions.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean certificate pinning for the *.firebaseio.com domains? For Firebase Hosting? For using the SDK on sites that use cert pinning?

Comment: sorry about not being clear , I mean for *.firebaseio.com domains.
Thanks for the attention

Answer (score 1):

Firebase does not support certificate pinning on `*.firebaseio.com` domains.

Comment: Just to make sure , I'm talking about communication between my clients using the node.js SDK to Firebase realtime database.

Comment: Do you plan to add support for certificate pinning in mobile applications? For example, in a react-native sdk?Thanks!